# How to create a flutter stateful widget that rotate its child?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, render

I'd like to create a stateful widget that embed other widget(s) to apply some form of custom rendering operations (such as rotation for example)

So I'd like to use my widget from a parent widget as follows:

```dart
     @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text(widget.title),
            ),
            body: _buildView(),
            floatingActionButton: StreamBuilder<bool>(
              stream: FlutterBlue.instance.isScanning,
              initialData: false,
              builder: (c, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.data) {
                  return FloatingActionButton(
                    child: Stack(alignment: Alignment.center, children: [
                      RotatingWidget(
                        child: ArcText(
                          radius: 34,
                          text: 'Radar scanning… | Radar scanning…',
                          textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.white),
                          startAngle: -3 * math.pi / 4,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Icon(Icons.stop),
                    ]),
                    onPressed: () => FlutterBlue.instance.stopScan(),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                  );
                }
                else 
                // Etc.
```

I came up with such a widget as follows, but I wonder how could I get the child to render it?

```
// Rotating button for the radar scanning
class RotatingWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  const RotatingWidget({Key key, @required this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RotatingWidgetState createState() => _RotatingWidgetState();
}
class _RotatingWidgetState extends State<RotatingWidget>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _controller =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 2))
          ..repeat();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: _controller,
        builder: (_, child) {
          return Transform.rotate(
            angle: _controller.value * 2 * math.pi,
            child: child,
          );
        },
        // ===== HOW TO GET THE CHILD PASSED TO THE CURRENT WIDGET ? ====
        child: this.state.child//FlutterLogo(size: 200),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `child: widget.child`

Comment: Thanks so much @pskink Turn it as an answer

Comment: your welcome, write a self answer then ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Merits go to @pskink for his quick answer:

You access to the child by writing:

```
   child: widget.child
```

instead of my wrong initial `child: this.child`